# element.classList.toggle is not working for a IMG element

Tags: javascript, html, class, toggle

I have an array of 3 image elements as it follows:

```
0: img.trendingGiffy
1: img.trendingGiffy
2: img.trendingGiffy


 favIcons.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            element.classList.toggle("lol")
        })
    });
```

By using above code it add the classes correctly to element 0 and element 2, however it doesn't work for the element 1.

Any clue why?

Comment: unfortunately, you have to provide  a verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.

```
     favIcons.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', elem => {
            elem.classList.toggle("lol")
        })
    });
```

As far as I know the arrow function does not not inherit the variable `element` (Because of different scope) and also add event listener callback has argument of the element itself, so you might try it.